# How to order values in ascending order from MySQL query with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-order-by

I am using the following PHP script to grab and alter data from a MySQL table and print the results in a HTML table. I was hoping to order the data in ascending order by the `$utilization_percentage` variable, which is created by `$total_client_time / $total_available_time * 100`. This occurs after the `$sql` query, so I am wondering if this can be accomplished with PHP? Or is there a way to alter the MySQL query to have the `$utilization_percentage` calculated within the query and then I can run a `ORDER BY` clause in the query? What would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
<?php

require_once 'tm-config.php';

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($tmcurrentConfig['host'], $tmcurrentConfig['user'], $tmcurrentConfig['pass'], $tmcurrentConfig['name']);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(t.available_time) AS total_available_time, 
                SUM(t.chargeable_time) AS total_chargeable_time, 
                SUM(t.admin_time) AS total_admin_time, 
                SUM(t.new_business_time) AS total_new_business_time, 
                c.name AS companyName 
        FROM Timesheet t 
        LEFT JOIN fos_user u ON(u.id = t.user_id) 
        LEFT JOIN company c ON(c.id = u.company_id) 
        GROUP BY u.company_id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $total_available_time = $row["total_available_time"];
  $total_chargeable_time = $row["total_chargeable_time"];
  $total_admin_time = $row["total_admin_time"];
  $total_new_business_time = $row["total_new_business_time"];
  $total_client_time = $total_chargeable_time + $total_admin_time + $total_new_business_time;
  $utilization = $total_client_time / $total_available_time;
  $utilization_percentage = $utilization * 100;
  $company_name = $row["companyName"];
  // echo data into HTML table
  echo
  "<tbody>" . "<tr>" . "<td>" . $company_name . "</td>" . "<td>" . round($utilization_percentage) . " %" . "</td>" . "</tr>" . "</tbody>";
 }
 } else {
 echo "No results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You can do this right in your query, just `((x + y + z) / a) AS u` and then `ORDER BY u ASC` kind of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate it in the query, and then use it in `ORDER BY`.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(t.available_time) AS total_available_time, 
                SUM(t.chargeable_time) AS total_chargeable_time, 
                SUM(t.admin_time) AS total_admin_time, 
                SUM(t.new_business_time) AS total_new_business_time, 
                c.name AS companyName,
                (SUM(t.chargeable_time) + SUM(t.admin_time) + SUM(t.new_business_time)) / SUM(t.available_time) * 100 AS utilization_percentage
        FROM Timesheet t 
        LEFT JOIN fos_user u ON(u.id = t.user_id) 
        LEFT JOIN company c ON(c.id = u.company_id) 
        GROUP BY u.company_id
        ORDER BY utilization_percentage";
```